# Is it feasible for a mobile app like a peer to peer torrent app to discover peers via Internet, not just direct Wifi?

Tags: internet, client-server, p2p, bittorrent, peering

If I create an app that will be installed on different devices (Windows, Android, Apple).

Different devices will be connected to Internet via different ISPs. Mostly devices will have changing dynamic IP address.

In this situation will it be possible for one client to find and communicate with all unknown devices connected to Internet and app installed. Like is it possible for one client to broadcast data to all other clients.

Is this potentially possible **WITHOUT USING ANY CENTRAL SERVER** for client to find **ALL** other clients?

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's possible, this is the way all peer-to-peer networks operate. And yes, this includes (any)Torrent and Bitcoin.

How to actually implement it, however, is *way* besides the scope of this site (or any site).

You can start from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer).